# How can you retrieve values from 3D arrays at the same 2D location?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have an array given by

```
A = array(1:8,c(2,2,2))
ind = which(A[,,1]>=2)
```

which yields

```
[1] 2 3 4
```

Now, how do I access the `2,3,4` values at each level in the third dimension (so, 2,3,4,6,7,8), but *not* 5?
`A[ind,]` obviously doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ind = which(A[,,c(1,2)]>=2,arr.ind=T)
A[ind]
```

EDIT

Get the index of one array from a multidimensional array:

```
A = array(1:8,c(2,2,2))
ind = which(A[,,1]>=2,arr.ind=T)
apply(A, 3, function(x) x[ind])
```

Comment: This gives me all values >= 2; I want the values at the same (x,y) location that A >= 2 in the first level of the third dimension, i.e., z=1. So, I want 2,3,4,6,7,8, but not 5.

Comment: like this?: `A[,,2][ind]`

Comment: What if the array was bigger, say, if there were 5 levels, and I wanted the values at every level?

Comment: @Alex You can manually write `A[ind[,1], ind[,2], ]` and so on. If you want something to programmatically handle well in higher dimensions, maybe you should give a more complicated example.

Comment: maybe this? `apply(A, 3, function(x) x[ind])`